# compress measurement data for charts, stored in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel-5

problem:
My application collects ~1000 datasets of different measurements every 5 minutes.
so every hour I collect 12.000 new datasets.

I need to export these data for charts: 1h, 24h, 1 day, 1 week, 1 month, 3 months, 6 months, 1 year, alltime

so safe some storage and for better performance, I want to compress these data.

Idea:
After 1 day, I can breakdown these data. Therefor I want to calc the avg of the 12 "5 min. measurements" to get  a value for 1 hours.

After maybe 1 week I can do the same for all "1h measurements" and calc the avg of 24 of them to get the avg value of the day.

I'm working in laravel (5.4).
The database looks like:

`id | identifier (unique) | value (float) | created_at (date)`

the server has 4 CPU 3.0 Ghz, 32 GB DDR3 RAM

now I'm looking for a performant algorithm to handle the big amount of data.

EDIT:
one idea could be to extract the big amount of data and their calculation of the SVG charts to the Google Platform (https://cloud.google.com/products/).the results could be posted to the live server - so this one doesn't calculate anything.

What do you think about that idea/(possible) solution? which if googles products would you recommend for that case?

Comment: Is performance a problem?

Comment: @Strawberry the charts are for a webapp usage - with a lot of active users. the speed is necessary for this application.

Comment: And speed is currently a problem?

Comment: at the moment the app is really fast. so it's not really a problem atm

Comment: In that case, don't worry about it. By the time it becomes a problem, either you'll be rich enough to hire a professional to sort it out, or too rich to care.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just use a separate MySQL table for histories, day, week etc.

Create a cronjob for at midnight and weekly, you could very performantly gather the results with a query like `SELECT AVG(value) FROM datasets WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2017-09-07' AND '2017-09-08' GROUP BY identifier`, store the results and delete the data from datasets table after successfully parsing it.

I think it will not even take minutes that way, although I would add an index on the date column.

Comment: thank you! I'll try that.
Do you think it's better to make a raw query or use Eloquent?

Comment: I'd always use an abstraction layer, so go with Eloquent if that suits your needs. It will make preventing sql injection less of a pain.